React key changes not dismounting component as expected
I created this component to animate a slow fade-in when it mounts:
const FadeInOnMount = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState<number>(0)
    useEffect(() => { setOpacity(1) }, [])
    return <span style={{
        opacity,
        transition: "opacity 2s ease-in",
    }}
    >{children}</span>
}

It works if I use it with a button to change state, like this:
const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState('a')
    return <>
        {/* a button you click to change the state: */}
        <div onClick={() => setState(s => s === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a')}>click me</div>

        {/* fade in state changes: */}
        <FadeInOnMount key={state}>
            {state}
        </FadeInOnMount>
    </>
}

But it DOESN'T work if I useEffect to change the state! The transition never appears!
    // does not fade properly if added to App:
    useEffect(() => {
        const iid = setInterval(() => setState(s => s === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a'), 5000)
        return () => clearInterval(iid)
    }, [])

What weirdness with the react lifecycle am I encountering?? The react documentation doesn't even try explaining its own lifecycle! What a world.

Note that you don't need to pass the generic param to useState when supplying a meaningful initial value like 0.

brilliant insight!
